# Minor support for Surface Pro 3

Tags: drivers, surface-tablet

I've gotten the install to boot, but now that the desktop is up, I can only interface through the touchscreen.
Drivers have not yet been installed for the WiFi card, mouse, or keyboard.

Does anyone know how to easily access these drivers or where to begin looking for them?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to use **neoreeps**'s Kernel (https://github.com/neoreeps/surface-pro-3), but don't expect everything to work.